# JavaFX how can I show different scenes of shapes on one stage, cause its only showing the last scene using netbeans

Tags: javafx, netbeans

In the code below it has three shapes with different scenes I want all of them to appear on the same stae but i'm finding it hard to show all the scenes in one stage, only the last scene appears on the stage.

''' //cubiccurve
Path path = new Path();

```
  //Moving to the starting point 
  MoveTo moveTo = new MoveTo(); 
  moveTo.setX(100.0); 
  moveTo.setY(150.0);
  
  //Instantiating the class CubicCurve 
  CubicCurveTo cubicCurveTo = new CubicCurveTo(); 
   
  //Setting properties of the class CubicCurve            
  cubicCurveTo.setControlX1(400.0f); 
  cubicCurveTo.setControlY1(40.0f); 
  cubicCurveTo.setControlX2(175.0f); 
  cubicCurveTo.setControlY2(250.0f); 
  cubicCurveTo.setX(500.0f); 
  cubicCurveTo.setY(150.0f);       
   
  //Adding the path elements to Observable list of the Path class 
  path.getElements().add(moveTo);       
  path.getElements().add(cubicCurveTo);         
  
  //Creating a Group object  
  Group curve = new Group(path); 

    Scene scene2 = new Scene(curve,600,300);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene2); 
     
  //Displaying the contents of the stage
  primaryStage.show();
```

'''
//quadcurve'''
QuadCurve quadCurve = new QuadCurve();

```
  //Adding properties to the Quad Curve 
  quadCurve.setStartX(100.0); 
  quadCurve.setStartY(220.0f); 
  quadCurve.setEndX(500.0f); 
  quadCurve.setEndY(220.0f); 
  quadCurve.setControlX(250.0f); 
  quadCurve.setControlY(0.0f);       
           
  //Creating a Group object  
  Group quad = new Group(quadCurve);
  
  //Creating a scene object 
  Scene scene3 = new Scene(quad, 600, 300); 
        primaryStage.setScene(scene3); 
     
  //Displaying the contents of the stage
  primaryStage.show(); 
  '''
'''//arc  
  //Creating an object of the class Arc         
   Arc arc = new Arc();
   //Setting the properties of the arc 
   arc.setCenterX(300.0f); 
   arc.setCenterY(150.0f); 
   arc.setRadiusX(90.0f); 
   arc.setRadiusY(90.0f); 
   arc.setStartAngle(40.0f); 
   arc.setLength(239.0f); 
   arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
   
   Group group = new Group(arc);
   Scene scene4 = new Scene(group ,600, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene4); 
     
  //Displaying the contents of the stage
  primaryStage.show();
```

'''

Comment: A stage can only have one scene

Comment: You could do `Pane root = new Pane(); root.getChildrent.addAll(curve, quad, group); Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400); primaryStage.setScene(scene);`